# Show by explicit calculation that $\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}_n, m\mapsto m\% n$ is a surjective ringhomomophism

Tags: ring-theory, proof-verification

> Consider $m\in\mathbb{Z}, n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then there exist unique elements $q\in\mathbb{Z}, r\in\mathbb{N}$ with $0\leq r<n$ and $m=qn+r$. We write $r:=m\% n$.
>   Show by explicit calculation that 
>   $$
> \varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}_n, m\mapsto m\% n
> $$ is a surjective ringhomomophism.

I am a little bit confused.

So here I have two rings
, namely $(\mathbb{Z},+,\cdot)$ with the usual addition and multiplication and $(\mathbb{Z}_n,\oplus,\odot)$, whereat last two operations are (as far as I know) defined by
$$
(x+n\mathbb{Z}) \oplus (y+n\mathbb{Z}):=(x+y)+n\mathbb{Z},~~~~~(x+n\mathbb{Z})\odot (y+n\mathbb{Z}):=(x\cdot y)+n\mathbb{Z}.
$$

So if I understand the function $\varphi$ right, it takes a $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and then maps this to the rest of the division $x : n$, which lies in one of the residue classes within $\mathbb{Z}_m$, i.e. is a representative of one residue class in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

What I have to show is that
$$
\varphi(x+y)=\varphi(x)\oplus\varphi(y),~~~ \varphi(x\cdot y)=\varphi(x)\odot\varphi(y)~~~\forall~x,y\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$

But I do not know how the operations $\oplus$ and $\odot$ are definied for representatives of residues classes.

Additionally, I do not know, what is meant with shwowing this by explicit calculation.

**Edit:** Here is my proof:

I.Ring homomorphism:

$$
\varphi(x+y)\\
=(x+y)\%n+n\mathbb{Z}\\
=(x\%n + y\% n)\% n + n\mathbb{Z}\\
=x\%n + n\mathbb{Z}\oplus y\%n+n\mathbb{Z}\\
=\varphi(x)\oplus\varphi(y)
$$
$$
\varphi(x\cdot y)\\
=(x\cdot y)\% n+n\mathbb{Z}\\
=(x\%\cdot y\%n)\%n+n\mathbb{Z}\\
=x\%n+n\mathbb{Z}\odot y\%n+n\mathbb{Z}\\
=\varphi(x)\odot\varphi(y)\\
$$

II. Surjectivity:

Consider any $z:=x\%n+n\mathbb{Z}\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ then $z=\varphi(x)$.

Pls write me in a comment if the proof is right and complete now, thanks.

Comment: What they mean is $\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}_n, m\mapsto m\% n + n\mathbb{Z}$.  They're not talking about mapping to a representative of a residue class, they're talking about mapping to the residue class itself.

Comment: Now I have the following for the addition: $\varphi(x+y)=(x+y)\%n+n\mathbb{Z}=(x\%n + y\% n)\% n + n\mathbb{Z}=x\%n + n\mathbb{Z}\oplus y\%n+n\mathbb{Z}=\varphi(x)\oplus\varphi(y)$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it seems fine.